# Adobe Edge alternatives

Tags: javascript, web-development, jquery

Are there similar software or alternative to Adobe Edge? I'm looking for a software where you can animate your html elements visually or using a GUI and then it will export in HTML and using javascript(jQuery if possible).

If there's none yet, I hope the jQuery (or other JS framework) community would develop a small app where you can just drag html elements, and animate it visually.